# Spring boot apps with JMS (ActiveMQ) over docker-compose: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, jms, activemq-classic

I've two spring boot app. I want to use JMS to send message from one app to another app. This app are running over docker-compose.

In client app, I've this:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {            
    @Value("${jmsDestination}")
    String jmsDestination;
    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
        URI location = new URI(jmsDestination);
        brokerService.addConnector(location);
        return brokerService;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {        
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);        
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

In client's application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/myDB
jmsDestination=tcp://eventual:6161
```

On server app, I've this:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {   

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {        
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);        
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

In server's application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/myDB
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://0.0.0.0:61616
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    client:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./config/Dockerfile_api
        expose:
            - '61616'
        ports:
            - "5000"
        restart: always
        links:
            - eventual
        depends_on:
            - eventual
    eventual:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./config/Dockerfile_eventual
        hostname: eventual
        expose:
            - '61616'
        ports:
            - "6000"
            - "61616:61616"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysqldb
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql/mysql-server:5.6.50
        container_name: mysql56
        restart: 'always'
        expose:
            - '3306'
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
```

Dockerfile_api flie:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD client.jar client.jar
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT exec java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar /client.jar
```

Dockerfile_eventual file:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD eventual.jar eventual.jar
EXPOSE 6000
ENTRYPOINT exec java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true $JAVA_OPTS -jar /eventual.jar
```

When I executed the command *docker-compose up*, the containers eventual and mysql up correctly, but the container client throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'broker' defined in class path resource [co/com/.../.../configuration/JmsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService]: Factory method 'broker' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://eventual:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
```

This exception is thrown at this line (on client app):

```
brokerService.addConnector(location);
```

Both apps are in the same network, and both apps can connect to database using this url:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/myDB
```

I have tried many different things without being able to find the solution. Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: is it possible that `client` and  `eventual` are trying to use the same port? it looks like you're exposing this port from the client and from the java container, did you mean to do so? and if so, why then? also, why are you publishing client port 5000 but exposing container port 61616?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't setup the apps in my machine yet, but does the client(producer) app need the `JmsListenerContainerFactory` bean? The error looks to be due to the fact that the client app binds to port `61616`, which I don't think it needs to, before the server(receiver) app can